Searching for a good video quality enhancer using AI
I have some old videos I made 15 years ago. Quality is very poor, it's really compressed and I have some glitches because video importation was very buggy at hthis time.
I want to try some programs which will be able to enhance these videos using AI.
I can even code this if there is just a model available. I search for a MacOS or Linux tool. I prefer if it's open source.
Do you know where I can find a good tool for that ? I tried some but quality was not that good. If there is no program do to it, how can I proceed in order to train my model ? I don't know if it's a good way to do it since it requires a lot of videos to do it...
Thanks!

I have used these AI video quality enhancement tools: AVCLabs Video Enhancer AI, Topaz Video Enhance AI, VideoProc. For me,  AVCLabs is the top choice. It provides powerful multiple AI models, including AI Enhancement, Face Enhancement, Colorize, and Motion Compensation, Anime, Denoise. It is a comprehensive tool for improving video quality.

Welcome Jennycaa! That's a helpful answer.  Can you provide a link to your answer?  Thanks, and again, welcome!

Acutually, open source free video enhance models are a bit hard to find, but I know of a software.It offers a 30 day free trial. Maybe you can try it. UniFab Video Enhancer which can improve video quality with AI.
It is user-friendly and supports upscale video resolution,remove video noise, and convert sdr to hdr(this is what attracts me most) And you can see the results compared with avclabs, another well known video enhancement program, which is still good.

Welcome Echo.  What affiliation, if any, do you have with the software you are recommending?  We require full disclosure at our community.  Thanks.

It definitely looks like self-promotion.  Please tour the help.

Blender Palladium addon is an implementation of a local offline front end for several AI tools and various models using Blender Video Sequence Editor as it interface.
It is free and open source and runs locally over Blender which is also free and open source. Doesn't require internet connection for operation, but does need an internet connection to set up initially, since each AI model download requires several gigabytes.
Among many other features it can make make video upscaling and improvement. From the feature list, emphasis mine

Features



Features





Text to video
Text to audio


Text to speech
Text to image


Image to image
Image to video


Video to video
Image to text


ControlNet
OpenPose


Canny
Illusion


Multiple LoRAs
Segmind distilled SDXL


Seed
Quality steps


Frames
Word power


Style selector
Strip power


Batch conversion
Batch refinement of images.


Batch upscale & refinement of movies.
Model card selector.


Render-to-path selector.
Render finished notification.


Model Cards
One-click install and uninstall dependencies.


User-defined file path for generated files.
Define the location for storing generated files.


Seed and prompt added to strip name.
Include seed and prompt information in the strip name.




May not be adequate for you because MacOs is not officially supported (though it may work with third party support), and requires a good NVidia graphics card with CUDA processing capabilities.
